# REST API request automation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rest, client

I created a class to automate some requests for an API. Can I improve this code in any way?

The code itself is very simple and easy to understand.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;

namespace Dummie
{
    public class AutoRequest
    {
        RestClient client;

        public CancellationTokenSource Cancel;

        string captchaResult = "";

        public AutoRequest(int timeout)
        {
            client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1");
            client.Timeout = timeout;
            client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

            Cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

        }

        private WebProxy ParseProxy(string proxy)
        {
            try
            {
                var p = proxy.Split(':');
                if (p.Count() > 2)
                {
                    var webproxy = new WebProxy(p[0], Convert.ToInt32(p[1]));
                    webproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(p[2], p[3]);
                    return webproxy;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new WebProxy(p[0], Convert.ToInt32(p[1]));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> TestProxy(string proxy)
        {
            client.Proxy = ParseProxy(proxy);

            var request = new RestRequest("http://127.0.0.1", Method.GET);

            var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, Cancel.Token);

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreatCookies(string apiCaptcha)
        {
            captchaResult = await SolveCaptchaAsync(apiCaptcha);

            var request = new RestRequest("http://127.0.0.1", Method.GET);

            var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, Cancel.Token);

            if(response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            return true;
        }

        private async Task<string> SolveCaptchaAsync(string apiCaptcha)
        {
            TwoCaptcha.Solve solver = new TwoCaptcha.Solve();
            var result = await solver.ReCaptchaV2Async(apiCaptcha, "6LeLvl", "http://127.0.0.1");
            return result.Request;
        }

        public async Task<string> SignUp()
        {

            var request = new RestRequest("http://127.0.0.1/api_test", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("g-recaptcha-response", captchaResult);

            var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, Cancel.Token);

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return "[ERROR] Failed during request. Status: " + response.StatusDescription;
            }

            if (response.ResponseUri.ToString() == "http://127.0.0.1/api_test?result=ok")
            {
                return "[OK] Account Successfully Created";
            }
            else
            {
                return "[ERROR] There was an error creating your account. URI: " + response.ResponseUri.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code is easy to understand. Could you summarize what it is exactly that it is automating?

Comment: sign up process